# Does boost::variant support 64bit integers?

Tags: c++, boost

I tried to use boost::variant combined with a 64 bit integer. Unfortunately it didn't work. Is there any way to fix this? Or is my boost version just to old? I'm using V1.45.

This declaration works:

```
std::vector< boost::variant<int, float64_t> > vec2;
```

This declaration doesn't work:

```
std::vector< boost::variant<long long int, float64_t> > vec2;
```

**Edit**

It's an compiler error:

```
error C2668: 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair,Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              BaseIndexPair=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>,boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<__int64,double,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>::initializer_node,boost::mpl::int_<1>>,boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<double,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>::initializer_node,boost::mpl::int_<2>>,
1>              Iterator=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>
1>          ]
1>          boost-1_45_0\boost\variant\detail\initializer.hpp(89): could be 'int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair,Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize(void *,const __int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              BaseIndexPair=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>,
1>              Iterator=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<__int64,double,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>
1>          ]
1>          boost-1_45_0\boost\variant\detail\initializer.hpp(89): or       'int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair,Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize(void *,const double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              BaseIndexPair=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>,boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<__int64,double,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>::initializer_node,boost::mpl::int_<1>>,
1>              Iterator=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<double,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(void *, const int)'
1>          boost-1_45_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1373) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::convert_construct<const T>(T &,int,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=__int64,
1>              T1=float64_t,
1>              T2=std::string,
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          (1900) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::variant<int>(const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=__int64,
1>              T1=float64_t,
1>              T2=std::string,
1>              T=int
1>          ]
```

**Edit**

The error was in the code not posted. @hvd has found the fault anyway. I must explicitly name the type - but only if it's an int64.

No error:

```
std::vector <boost::variant <int, float64_t> > vec;
vec.push_back ( 22 );
```

Compiler error:

```
std::vector <boost::variant <__int64, float64_t> > vec;
vec.push_back ( 22 );
```

No error:

```
std::vector <boost::variant <__int64, float64_t> > vec;
vec.push_back ( (__int64) 22 );
```

Comment: compiles using boost 1.59: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zIoFXtoUd8W5513Q

Comment: What doesn't work ? Compiler error (which one) ?

Comment: Old MSVC version? `__int64` is a bit suspect. BTW, you really should post minimal examples. If that `, std::string` type isn't needed to reproduce the error, leave it out.

Comment: This could be the problem. I'm using VS2010. When using the link from @m.s. I had no problems with old boost versions but switching the compiler to C++03 I got errors.

Comment: The error says you're trying to put an int in your variant, right? Well that *is* ambiguous... it could be converted to either type.

Comment: The 64 bit support depends of your plattform, you can use c++11?
std::int_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a short answer: boost::variant does support 64bit integers.

But if the value assigned to boost::variant is ambiguous this can lead to compiler errors (e.g. the boost::variant does support float and integers and you try to assign an integer). In this case an explicit typ conversion solves the problem.